# Putnam 2015 and Ravi Substitution

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, geometric-inequalities

Let $T$ be the set of all triples $(a,b,c)$ of positive integers for which there exist triangles with side lengths $a,b,c$. Express

$$\sum_{(a,b,c)\in T}\frac{2^a}{3^b5^c}$$

as a rational number in lowest terms.

One of the solutions is as follow:

Let $a=\frac{y+z}{2}, b=\frac{z+x}{2}, c=\frac{x+y}{2}.$

Then $x,y,z$ are either all even or all odd. Hence the original sum equals

$$\sum_{x,y,z>0 \ odd}\frac{2^{(y+z)/2}}{3^{(z+x)/2}5^{(x+y)/2}}+\sum_{x,y,z>0 \ even}\frac{2^{(y+z)/2}}{3^{(z+x)/2}5^{(x+y)/2}}$$.

Then after a substitution, we can unify the two sums and obtain a geometric series and we are done.

I have two questions.

First, why the substitution $a=\frac{y+z}{2}, b=\frac{z+x}{2}, c=\frac{x+y}{2}$ instead of the "ordinary" ravi substitution $a=y+z, b=z+x, c=x+y$? I know they are also equivalent conditions for a triangle to exist, but this is the first time I see this substitution (divided by 2). Is it possible to evaluate the sum using the ordinary ravi substitution?

Second, I don't understand why $x,y,z$ are either all odd or all even in order to generate all the triangles...

Thanks!

Comment: Check what happens to the integer sides if one among $x, y, z$ has a different parity.

Comment: Thanks, it is obvious if we use the substitution $a=(y+z)/2$, but what if I use the substitution $a=y+z$? is it possible to evaluate the sum?

Comment: Then you would have to worry about the domain of $x, y, z$ needed to get all integer triangles, and only integer triangles.  For e.g. how will you get the triangle $a=b=c=3$? Note the so called "Ravi substitution" is commonly used for real numbers, not integers.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much!